Why can't a derived class in Python reference inherited attributes in its definition?
I have this snippet:
class A(object):
    def foo():
        pass

class B(A):
    bar = foo()

As written, this file will fail to run with the error NameError: name 'foo' is not defined. However, since foo is defined in A, and is inherited by B, I should be able to access them.
I know I can simply access foo in the __init__ method of B, but I want to access it in the top-level definition.

You can't, inherited class B has to be constructed first. Just like you couldn't do this in your Class A

The idea that you "should" be able to access "foo" directly here is unfounded. Consider a class B(A1, A2) and both A1 and A2 implement foo. What would an unqualified "foo" in the body of class B refer too?

@wim Whichever foo self.foo would refer to (so probably, A1.foo).

During the class definition block, the class hasn't been defined yet, so the MRO (which determines where self.foo resolves) doesn't yet exist.

@wim When Python reaches the class definition, doesn't the interpreter already know what the parent class/classes is/are?

Knowing the bases is weaker than solving the mro. Looks like the class block gets exec before the mro is constructed.

This could solve
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = self.foo()


Well, I know about that, but I want it to be in the top-level definition.

You can't use foo() inside the class declaration because there's no instance or context for A.
You can do something like this instead.
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

class B(A):
    bar = A.foo()


The most "top-level" definition would be to add the @staticmethod decorator to foo as shown below:
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

class B(A):
    bar = A.foo # Direct reference to foo() in A without calling it.

# Can still access without instantiating B
B.bar

This is not reliant on instance-specific data, so it is suitable for top-level definitions.
I hope this answers your question.
